# "ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant" when returning the resultant dataframe of a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fastapi

I wrote a function that fills the missing values of chosen columns of a dataframe with the mean of that column.

**Mean function**

```
def miss_mean_fun(df,col):
  df[col].fillna(df[col].mean(), inplace=True)
  df[col] = df[col].round(decimals=2)
  return df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

**Main function**

```
def cleaning_and_analysis(csv_filepath, operation=None, raw_data=None):
     csv_dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_filepath) 
     result={}
     if raw_data is not None and isinstance(raw_data, list):
        for i in raw_data:    
          if operation == 'fill_with_mean':
               fill_with_mean_input = i
               result7=miss_mean_fun(csv_dataframe, fill_with_mean_input)
               if not result:
                  result[operation] = [{i:result7}]
               else:
                  result[operation].append({i:result7})
        return result
```

**My API**

```
@app.post("/data_cleaning_route")
async def data_cleaning_file(item: Item):
    filepath = item.filepath
    operation_name = item.operation
    operands = item.operand
    cleaned_data = {} # initialize cleaned_data to an empty dictionary
    if len(operands) >=1:
        for i in operands:
            if isinstance(i, dict): # check if i is a dictionary
                for operation_name, operand_values in i.items():
                    cleaned_data.update(cleaning_and_analysis(filepath, operation=operation_name, raw_data=operand_values))
    return cleaned_data
```

**My postman payload**

```
{
"filepath": "Downloads/water_consumption.csv",
"operation": "handling missing values",
"operand":[ {"fill_with_mean":["f.1_ENE_09", "f.1_JUN_10"]}]
            }
```

The above code gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant
```

I executed the above code in Google Colab & it gave me the expected output, i.e, values of each column in a dictionary. But when run through an API, it is giving the above error.

Where have I gone wrong?

**Traceback Error**:

```
Traceback error: File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode return _iterencode(o, 0). 

"`result[operation] = [{i:result7}]`" --> Error appears here.
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Note: `for raw_data in raw_data:` that can't end well: overwriting the list variable name with the elements variable name. Use e.g. `for raw_item in raw_data:`.

Comment: `for col in columns_list:` this steps through one element of the "fill_with_mean", that is, `columns_list` is e.g. "f.1_ENE_09". Possibly because of the above mentioned problem. So looping through that is looping through each single character, and the first charcter is "f". Which is where your error ultimately comes from.

Comment: You basically have one loop too many. Remove one of the above mentioned loops, and you might be good to go.

Comment: I removed the "for col in columns_list:" loop. Now I'm getting the error: ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant. I updated my code in the question. When I return the updated columns, there's no issue, but returning the entire dataframe is giving the "json" error. Why?

Comment: You updated the code, but not the error, nor did you add a traceback to your question. Those are very useful for debugging.

Comment: You also still have the `for raw_data in raw_data:`loop. You can change that to e.g. `for fill_with_mean_input in raw_data:`, then remove the `fill_with_mean_input = raw_data` line.

Comment: You could have searched for the new ValueError, and you'll find that you (still) have NaNs in your results. Given that you mention the enitre dataframe shows the problem, but not the updated columns, that sounds as if there are NaNs in other columns.

Comment: I did change 'raw_data' to 'i' after the suggestion. Forgot to mention that here. Got the 'json' error after the change. Updated my question with all the changes made.

Comment: You updated the code, but you still forgot to update the error and add the traceback. Since the title and question itself still ask about the keyerror: that has been answered, and solved.

Comment: Traceback error: File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0). "result[operation] = [{i:result7}]" --> Error appears here.

Comment: To reiterate: you likely have NaNs in your dataframe, and JSON can't encode those. Why it works in Google Colab, I don't know, but we also don't know what code you use there. You should carefully check your dataframe for any NaNs. Or try with `csv_dataframe.fillna(0)` and see if you get the same error. If this error disappears, then the problem are NaNs/empty fields in your input data.